# "Missing artifact" errors with company repository

Tags: java, maven-2, dependencies, artifactory

I setup a company maven repository using artifactory. I deployed a project of us into the repository. If I now specify a dependency to that artifact, it doesn't get retrieved. Which it should, because I declared this in my settings.xml:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>company-internal</id>
    <name>company repository</name>
    <url>http://company.repository:8080/artifactory/repo/</url>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

This works for all 3rdparty dependencies. The artifact is definitely in the reposity, manually I can download the artifact just fine. Why is maven not able to download it? Is it more likely to be a problem with maven (or the configuration there), or is there a bug in artifactory? Is there something which is handled differently in case of SNAPSHOTs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to add your company repository under the ["repositories" element](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories).

The "mirrors" element is for specifying local mirrors for repositories like "central".

Answer (score 0):

it should work, can you give more informations ?

- dependency snippet you use to get the artifact
- pom.xml of the artifact in the repository